# Convert directory of files from .docx to .md using pandoc

Tags: markdown, pandoc

I have a directory with around 6,000 .docx files.

I want these files to all be converted to markdown (.md).

I am familiar with rudimentary command line commands, but that's about it. I do not know how to use a "make" file, for example.

I am able to convert one file at a time using pandoc, but I cannot figure out how to convert the entire directory.

How do I do this?

Comment: are you on linux/mac? (then you can use bash scripting) or are you familiar with any programming language like python or ruby?

Comment: Windows machine. I am familiar with ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the following ruby script in say `convert.rb`, then go to the desired directory on the commandline (I think it's called PowerShell in Windows) and execute it with `ruby convert.rb`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

Dir.glob('*.docx') do |file|
  exec 'pandoc ' + file + ' -o ' + file + '.md'
end
```